# I have written a java program whose dry-run is showing the proper result but on running the program, it shows no output

Tags: java

This is my Java program that should print the neon number between the given limit.
A number is said to be neon if sum of all the digits of a square of a number is equal to the entered number.

Example

1. Square of `9 = 81`
2. Sum of `8 + 1 = 9`

Please, could someone explain what is wrong here with my current implementation?

Here is my program

```
import java.util.*;
class neon
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    Scanner me = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("  What's about the lower limit ?   ");
    int l=me.nextInt();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("  What's about the upper limit ?   ");
    int h=me.nextInt();
    System.out.println();
    int sum=0;
    for(int i=l;i<=h;i++)
    {
        int ii=i*i;
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            int a=ii%10;
            ii=ii/10;
            sum=sum+a;
            if(sum==i)
            {
                System.out.println(i+"\t");
                break;
            }
        }

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me, try it and let me know :

```
import java.util.*;
class neon
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    Scanner me = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("  What's about the lower limit ?   ");
    int l=me.nextInt();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("  What's about the upper limit ?   ");
    int h=me.nextInt();
    System.out.println();
    for(int i=l;i<=h;i++)
    {
        int sum=0;
        int ii=i*i;
        while(ii!=0){   
            int a=ii%10;
            ii=ii/10;
            sum+=a;
        }
        if(sum==i)
        {
            System.out.println(i+"\t");
            break;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second loop `for(int j=0;j<3;j++)` is upper bound by 3, so it won't work for numbers >31 (32*32 = 1024 => 4 digits).

Also, you need to remove that `break`, because you are not testing all digits of `ii`.

Answer (score 0):

I' not entirely sure about your code, but I just did a small test and I think you want to put your

```
int sum=0;
```

into your for-loop, so it gets reset for every number in your test range:

```
for(int i=l;i<=h;i++)
    {
        int sum=0;
        int ii=i*i;
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            //Your code
        }
    }
```

This worked for me at least, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

- You have to add sum = 0 inside first for loop.
- Take the if loop out from second for loop and remove break;
- Suggestion : Get the square root number length as upper limit in inner for loop.

Below you can find the code

```
public class neon
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    Scanner me = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("  What's about the lower limit ?   ");
    int l=me.nextInt();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("  What's about the upper limit ?   ");
    int h=me.nextInt();
    System.out.println();
    int sum;
    for(int i=l;i<=h;i++)
    {
        sum=0;
        Integer ii=i*i;
        for(int j=0;j<=Integer.toString(ii).length();j++)
        {
            int a=ii%10;
            ii=ii/10;
            sum=sum+a;
        }
        if( sum == i )
        {
            System.out.println(i+"\t");
        }
    }
  }
}
```